# Setter Injection Using Java Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a  Runnable (i.e. a Class Implementing Runnable). There is one SpringBean where i am using this Runnable  by calling its Contstructor. I want to make this Runnable a Spring Bean.

Ex.

```
Class RunTest implements Runnable {

    Object object;

    public RunTest(Object a){
        this.object=a;
    }

    public void run() {
        //using attributes of a 
    }

}
```

Now I have a Spring Bean

```
@Named
Class TestSpringBean {

    public void someMethod(){
        Object a;
        new RunTest(a)
    }

}
```

Can i inject RunTestClass inside TestSpringBean and use.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot or plain Spring Framework? Are you using Java configuration or XML? Is it a web application?

Comment: This post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094452/autowiring-tasks-sent-to-spring-taskexecutor

Comment: Plain Spring Framework and using Java Configuration

Comment: @AnjaniKumar can you clarify on Object that you are using in someMethod? do you consider it as an injected bean in TestSpringBean or it is not known in startup phase?

Answer (score 1):

Mark the class `RunTest` as a `@Component`, inject its instance into the class `TestSpringBean`, and complete the configuration in the method `someMethod`*:

```
@Component
class RunTest implements Runnable {
    public RunTest() {}
}

class TestSpringBean {

    @Autowired
    private RunTest runnable;

    public void someMethod() {
        ...
        runnable.set(a);
    }

}
```

*Note that you are supposed to get an already-configured component, so no other configurations are required. It's a singleton instance, so the changes here will be reflected in other places as well.

In other words, singletons should remain stateless. That's why this simple solution should be revised by either finding a way to obtain a complete object or excluding that object from the task class.

**You might change the scope to `"prototype"`, but Spring still couldn't provide a fully-configured instance. It raises a question: should Spring manage this class at all?

***As pointed out by @lucumt, make sure that the class is visible for the component scan mechanism.

Comment: Also need to make sure the application can search and find the `RunTest` class

Answer (score 0):

**Description:**

> `TaskExecutor` is as an abstraction for dealing with executors that is
>   introduced since Spring 2.0.Spring’s TaskExecutor interface can be considered as identical to the `java.util.concurrent.Executor` interface. There are also a number of built-in implementations of `TaskExecutor` included with the Spring distribution. read them here :
>   https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/scheduling.html

---

**How To:**

**1. Define a `TaskExecutor` configuration to your spring application:**

```
@Configuration
public class MultiThreadConfig {

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {

        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("DEFAULT");
        executor.initialize();

        return executor;
    }

}
```

**2. Define you runnable as Prototype**

- *Make sure you change Object to your required custom type*

  ```
  @Component
  @Scope("prototype")
  public class RunTest implements Runnable {

      @Autowired
      ChangeObjectToYourNeed object ;

      public RunTest(ChangeObjectToYourNeed a) {
          this.object = a;
      } 

      @Override
      public void run() {
          // your code
      }
  }
  ```

**3. Inject the executor to your services in order to execute runnable instances:**

```
@Service
public class AsynService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void executeAsync() {
        RunTest runTest = applicationContext.getBean(MyThread.class);
        taskExecutor.execute(runTest);
    }

}
```

Comment: how will `Object object` be injected?

Comment: Object should be changed to his needs, i just placed it as his code, but let me change it, thanks @AndrewTobilko

Comment: OP is getting `Object object` in the `someMethod` method, it isn't known during the start-up

Comment: I assumed by that he wanted to be concise, and what he wants is that TestSpringBean is a manged spring bean where object injected there  which is then passed to runnable constructor.however let me ask him to clarify on this .